# OpenGL texture not working

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, texture2d

I'm trying to learn how to use textures in OpenGL. I started reading the chapter on texture mapping in OpenGL Redbook. I didn't understand it so I googled and found [this tutorial](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html). I followed instructions and I still am not able to get it to work. [This](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2170) is the code.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG616.jpg) is my texture image . I used Photoshop to convert it in to [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?130w6o9tmbdi4ut). The size of the file is 175KB which is about the right size (200x300x3=180000).

I tried to read the file in another program and see if the contents are right. It seems I can only read about 221 pixels (it's approx. the first line of image) and it reaches eof(). In my program I read as much as I expect in there to be, but when I debugged I noticed after some points bytes are **zeroed**.

Now I'm confused. Is there a problem with my program? Is there a problem with texture? Is there a problem with me? What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code. You attempt to read a binary file with text mode. Instead use the following code:

```
ifstream tex("ace.raw", ios::in | ios::binary);
if(tex.is_open())
  for(int j=0; j<imH; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<imW; ++i)
      for(int k=0; k<3; ++k)
      {
        face[j][i][k] = tex.get();
      }

tex.close();
```

Or much shorter and equivalent code:

```
ifstream tex("ace.raw", ios::in | ios::binary);
if (tex.is_open())
  tex.read((char*)face, sizeof(face));

tex.close();
```

Both codes are tested and "face" variable consists exactly same contents as "ace.raw".

Comment: To my surprise, this seems to solve it. What's the difference in reading a file in text mode or binary mode?! it should contain same data, shouldn't it?

Comment: In text mode, you're limited to printable ASCII range and some values can control the behaviour of the reader while binary mode simply reads whatever you've stored.

Answer (score -1):

How does the texture appear? Is it garbage? Is it just pure white (i.e. no texture)? Depending on your graphics card, it might be possible that your textures require a power of two as width/height and/or your texture has to be a square. Does it work without using mipmaps?

Even without being able to read the complete file or having some corrupted data in there, you should at least see some garbage as texture if reading the file goes crazy.

Comment: It used to be black (reading zeroes). Then after editing it a bit, it turned gray-ish white. No power of two textures are not the case since Osman's solution worked. Without mipmaps it has the same results.

Answer (score -2):

No, there is no problem. Images can contain many zero bytes, to read it all without missing anything, make sure to stat its size.

Comment: I'm reading the whole file in a loop 200x300x3 and reading RGB information, ignoring the fact that I'm reading zeroes. The problem is that it actually displays zeroes(black texture) too! which is wrong. I uploaded the actual image so you could see what it looks like.